# How to replace &quot; output in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, iframe, laravel-blade

I have this ajax request to display data into a modal.

But I'm stuck at adding the value into URL link. The code is as below.

In console, I see that the output has **quot** in it. How do I replace/remove it ? I cannot add the output into pdfUrl variable. Output in console show like this

```
GET http://localhost:8000/folder/&quot;+category1+&quot;/test.pdf 404 (Not Found)
```

**test.js**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/getpdf",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {"id": id},
    success: function(data)
    {  
        var ar = data;  

        var category        = ""; 

        for (var i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) 
        { 
            category        = ar[i]['category'];    
        }     

        var category1 = category.replace(/&quot;/g, '\\"');
        console.log(category1);

        var pdfUrl = "{{ URL::to('/folder/"+category1+"/test.pdf') }}";
        $(".iframeDoc1").attr("src", pdfUrl).show();  

        $('#modal_show').modal({
            show: true
        });  

    },
    error: function(error){
            console.log("Error:");
            console.log(error);
    }
});
```

Output in console.

[image]

Appreciate if someone can help me on this issue. Thanks.

Comment: What is the value of ar[0]['category']?

Comment: First, the `for` loop seems to be redundant. The `category` variable will have the last value received in `data`. Is this correct?

Also, why not define `pdfUrl` simply as `'/folder/' + category1 + '/test.pdf'`? What is that `URL::to` part?

Comment: @mrblue . Output for category is 1

Comment: @RomiHalasz . Im using laravel . i want to pass the value into blade

Comment: But laravel is php, this code is js.

Answer (score 1):

you can use replace function.

```js
var data="http://localhost:8000/folder/&quot;+category1+&quot;/test.pdf"
data=data.replace(/&quot;/g,'')
console.log(data)
```